# setInterval is not a function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

`var intervalID = setInterval(funkey2, inter)();`

In the Chrome console, I get this error:

[image]

but when I don't have line 24, the function never runs. The stop button doesn't work for some reason. I'm using `setInterval` for the first time so thanks for the help.

Comment: Try using just `var intervalID = setInterval(funkey2, inter);` without `()` at last.

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't return a function. It returns an intervalId as per the name of your variable.

Comment: `intervalID ` it's not a function

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` returns a number representing the ID of the timer. This is useful when used with the `clearInterval` method which cancels the timer you set.

```
var intervalID = setInterval(funkey2, inter)();
```

You define a variable `intervalID` and give it the return value of `setInterval` on line 23, but you try to run it as a function on line 24.

It's like writing

```
var num = 4;
num();
```

which will return the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a anonymous function:

```
var intervalID = function(){
    setInterval(funkey2, inter);
}
```

And call it:

```
intervalID();
```

Comment: This may prevent the error, but this is likely not what OP wants to do.